# Making pushstate work with both href and javascript

Tags: javascript, pushstate

I'm using javascript pushstate to change the URL of the current page, when a link i clicked:

```
<a href="/some-page/" onclick="url_go('/some-page/'); return false;">
```

I want to allow right-clicking on the link and opening in new window - as well as CTRL+click should open in new tap. But it doesn't.

How can I make both normal clicking work (pushstate) and CTRL+click (new tap) work?

(Facebook does it, but I cannot see how).

Comment: It appears my example got lost. Here it is again:

<a href="/some-page/" onclick="url_go('/some-page/'); return false;">

Comment: It wasn't lost, you had to to add 4 spaces before the line with code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you want your own event handler for Click, but leave the default behavior for Ctrl+Click or Scroll Button Click. I haven't found where exactly facebook does it (it always handles clicks and ctrl+clicks in the same way), but it can be achieved by code.

You should remove the `onclick` attribute from the HTML element and move it to javascript. Then check the `event` parameter for the `ctrlKey` property. You can do this by using the code like `if (e.which > 1 || e.ctrlKey)` or use a more complex function from a website similar to facebook:

```
function shouldUseDefault(e) {
    return ((e = (e || window.event)) && (e.type == 'click' || e.type == 'mousedown' || e.type == 'mouseup') && (e.which > 1 || e.button > 1 || e.ctrlKey || e.shiftKey || browser.mac && e.metaKey)) || false;
}
```

Then use it so in plain javascript:

```
<a id="some-link-id" href="http://google.com">Test link</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    var link = document.getElementById("some-link-id");
    link.addEventListener("click", function(clickEvent) {
        if (shouldUseDefault(clickEvent) === false) {
            url_go(link.href);
            clickEvent.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Or in jQuery if you want to support older browsers like Internet Explorer 8:

```
$(function() {
    $("#some-link-id").on("click", function(clickEvent) {
        if (shouldUseDefault(clickEvent) === false) {
            url_go(clickEvent.currentTarget.href);
            clickEvent.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```